# Are questions about browsers/plug-ins/add-ons appropriate?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, questions, private-beta

Are questions about browsers, plug-ins, add-ons and features appropriate for Web Apps?

For example is this question: [Google Chrome Password manager](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/604/google-chrome-password-manager) something that should be asked here or at [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: That question is off-topic for other reasons.

Answer (score 14):

I think we'd have to use the same rule we use on Super User, but in reverse:

> is the **primary focus of the question the website?**

In other words, I think it's OK, if the question can be read

> I need my browser to do this so it works better with {specific website}

If it's just a general

> how do I get my web browser to do {stuff}

then, no.

Comment: So does the "Google Chrome Password manager" question fit the category of "how do I get my browser to do stuff" or "I need my browser to do this so it works better with {specific website}"?

Comment: No but it makes using Web Apps easier, but the wording should be rephrased to: how can I make it easier to log into Web Apps using Google Chrome?

Comment: @sim for that one, I would say, no -- it doesn't fit and is not appropriate for Web Apps.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about browsers should go to [Super User](http://superuser.com), especially ones about plugins and other enhancements.

I agree that it's a grey area, but we need to be clear about the distinction.

If this site takes off there will be a migration path between the two sites (both ways).

Comment: That seems right, however I see that plugins/extensions and other browser features could be the answer to some questions, but that's fine I would say.

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually vouch against asking them on Super User @ChrisF

If they are questions to modify a website or web app, I would move them here since they are **more** on-topic here, than they are on Super User

Answer (score 1):

If the plug-in is **not useful** if you are **not a user of a given web app**, I think the questions is OK.

But if the plug-in is useful for most (or a lot) of web sites, I don’t think the question is OK.

However “use plug-in X” could be a good **answer** to a lot of questions.

Answer (score -2):

I think questions about add-ons or plug-ins that are related to WebApps are legitimate but that is a grey area based on the two criteria that Jeff Atwood refers to in his answer.

I don't think the general browser questions should be verboten as the browser is the main method of accessing WebApps and it would be good to keep those questions here rather than shunting them off to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).