# Are questions about browsers accepted as long as they are related to using a web application?

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-proposed

There already are questions about bookmarklets but are questions about browsers (plugins, features) accepted (as long as they are related to using a real web application?).

For example, questions about Greasemonkey, plugins to enhance a web apps' experience, Google Chrome's application shortcut feature, etc.

Personally I would say yes, but I'd like to know the community's point of view.

Note: This could go in the FAQ (as on or off-topic depending on the result).

Example of such a question: [What are the most useful plugins for Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-are-the-most-useful-plugins-for-gmail)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions about browsers appropriate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/are-questions-about-browsers-appropriate)