# The Tour appears to give contradictory advice about browser questions

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, tour

The [tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) instructs new users:

> Ask about... Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)

and later

> Don't ask about... Web browsers, including features and browser extensions/add-ons

The first one says that some browser questions are on topic, the second one says that all browser questions are off-topic. It's not obvious which one has higher priority.

Should the second be qualified similarly to the first? E.g., "Don't ask about... Usage of web browsers that is not specific to a web application"

I understand this is a nuanced issue, at least according to some 5-year-old meta posts:

- [Are questions about browsers appropriate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/are-questions-about-browsers-appropriate)
- [Are questions about browsers accepted as long as they are related to using a web application?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/are-questions-about-browsers-accepted-as-long-as-they-are-related-to-using-a-web)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have amended the [tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) to be more specific on what is allowed. The **Ask About...** section now states:

> - [Augmented browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_browsing) extensions that directly relate to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application,
>     etc.)

I have left the **Don't ask about...** section as it is. Hopefully that will clear up any confusion.